# Maximal ideal of codimension >1

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

To assuage my conscience over an unsourced statement in a paper I'm writing:

I am looking for an example of a commutative algebra over the complex numbers having a maximal ideal of codimension >1, or a statement of inexistence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the codimension is finite, then there is no such thing. If the codimension can be infinite, then yes, because there are infinite dimensional complex division algebras which are simple, like $\mathbb C(t)$.

Comment: I like the bit about the codimension being necessarily infinite. Where could I find a proof of that? What kinds of techniques are involved?

Comment: Miguel, if a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ has finite codimension in your $\mathbb C$-algebra $A$, then $A/\mathfrak m$ is a finite dimensional commutative $\mathbb C$-algebra which is simple. It is therefore a finite dimensional division $\mathbb C$-algebra, and it must then be of dimension $1$, as it is in fact an agebraic field extension of $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 4):

By codimension you just mean as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space?  Take the rational function field $\mathbb{C}(t)$.

(Note: by the Nullstellensatz, it is not possible to do so with a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.)

Comment: Thanks, Pete - I knew about the Nullstellensatz but I am indeed interested in infinitely generated algebras.